# Chrome: Passing data between contentscript and popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I've got a simple function that just passes `location.href` from contentscript to the popup.html page. It's not working. what I've got is..

in popup.html..

```
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab)
            {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest({req: "getlocation"}, function(response){
            return response.reply;
            });
            });
```

in my contentscript...

```
        case "getlocation":
        sendResponse({
            reply: location.href
            });
     break;
```

Why isn't my code working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some params are missing, plus you can't use `return` from an async callback function.

**popup.html:**

```
function getCurrentUrl(callback){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {req: "getlocation"}, function(response){
            callback(response.reply);
        });
    });
}

getCurrentUrl(function(url){
    console.log("url:", url);
});
```

**content_script.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.req) {
        case "getlocation": 
            sendResponse({
                reply: window.location.href
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats the `callback` param you have?

Comment: @Skizit I assumed your code in popup is a part of some utility function because you are using `return` there.  You can't use `return` with received value inside `chrome.tabs.sendRequest`, you need to pass received value to some other function, I made it so it will be passed to a `callback` function. If you don't need to pass received url anywhere then you can just do everything inside `chrome.tabs.sendRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

sendRequest is outdated.

use [sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage)